# dedicated server and unix sockets

Tags: dedicated-server

I have an OpenVZ VPS and for some reasons I have run out of the non-TCP sockets:

```
cat /proc/user_beancounters 
uid  resource    held      maxheld   barrier    limit     failcnt
numothersock     40        2002      2000       2000      4683
```

An application uses unix-sockets very heavily, up to 4683 as to the listing above. That is the reason, I am going to move to dedicated server.

Question. How do I find out of how many unix-sockets I am allowed to open on a dedicated server?

I think the server's configuration is not a big matter in this case, but I would like to buy a server with CPU 2x2.50GHz, RAM 4G, HDD 80G, CentOS 5.7, Apache 2.2. Sorry, I can't probably formulate a question correctly.

Comment: Eugh. OpenVZ.  You've just found yet another reason why this is a "toy" solution for "virtualisation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, for maximum number of file descriptors, you can:
    cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max

here's one for my little ol' laptop:

```
zsh 15427 [1] % cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
403568
```

it all depends on the distro, kernel limits, kernel features, hardware.... there isn't really any firm metric for it.